# Alert Dialog positive button does not wait until Async Firestore request call completed?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-alertdialog

I have `AlertDialog` with a custom layout to sign in users, which check if it is user's first time signing in by checking the Firestore for the existence of their email.

```
private fun showSignInDialog() {

     val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
     builder.setTitle("Sign In")
     val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
     val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_sign_in, null)
     builder.setView(dialogView)
     val editEmail = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_email)
     val editPassword = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_password)

     builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
        val email = editEmail.text.toString()
        val password = editPassword.text.toString()
        signInWithEmail(email, password)
     }
     builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ -> dialog.cancel() }
     builder.create().show()
}

private fun signInWithEmail(email: String, password: String) {
     auth = Firebase.auth
     auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
                    val signedInEmail = auth.currentUser?.email
                    firestoreService = FirestoreService()

                    firestoreService.doesUserAlreadyExists(object : UserCallback {
                        override fun onCallback(dRef: String) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "dRef = $dRef")
                            if (dRef.isEmpty())
                                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_signIn_to_ceateProfile)
                            else
                                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_signIn_to_main)
                        }
                    }, signedInEmail!!)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
}
```

**FirestoreService.kt**

```
class FirestoreService {

    private val db = Firebase.firestore

    fun doesUserAlreadyExists(callback: UserCallback, email: String) {
        db.collection("Users")
            .whereEqualTo("email", email).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    val docRef = document.id
                    callback.onCallback(docRef)
                    Log.d(TAG, "docRef = $docRef")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.w(TAG, "Error adding User document", e)
            }
    }
}
```

But this `doesUserAlreadyExists` never get executed, this is probably because since this method is async and there is nothing to return to after the finish of async callback, since dialog is destroyed by that time. How could I make this work?

**Update :**

I tried same logic on fragments instead of dialogs, same outcome, It seems something have to do with the `firestoreService.doesUserAlreadyExists` inside the `addOnCompleteListener` since one async callback is inside an another async callback. How to fix this?

Comment: Is the onSucces or onFailre even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo neither of them.

Comment: @AlexMamo debugger does not even step inside the `doesUserAlreadyExists`

Comment: In that case, most likely you don't have an internet connection on the user's device, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I do have connection to internet, sign up work fines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was there was no "Users" collection to check since I have deleted the "Users" collection so neither `addOnSuccessListener` or `addOnFailureListener` was called.

I wish there was an exception being thrown when a collection does not exist.

It is always to better to use `addOnCompleteListener` over `addOnSuccessListener` listener since it is guaranteed to be triggered no matter what

ex:

```
db.collection(USER_COLLECTION)
        .whereEqualTo("email", email).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->

            if(task.isSuccessful){
                for (document in task.result) {
                        if (document.exists()) {
                             //..
                        }
                 }
            }
            else{
                //..
            }
        }
```